# Position a fixed div below another fixed div with variable height without using jquery

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed top div with variable height. All I need is to push the bottom contents below the fixed div to re-position itself as the height of the fixed div changes in various pages.

P.S. I'm currently doing it with jquery but it takes some rendering time and shows broken contents until the page loads completely as it is added at the end of body tag. I want to load jquery and other scripts at the very end so trying to find a way to do this completely with CSS if possible for getting rid of those rendering effects.

Following is a demo code which needs to work with CSS only -

```css
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .top {
      position: fixed;
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      top: 0;
    }

    .bottom {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="top">
    This is a fixed div with variable height and the bottom content are supposed to pushed and stayed below as the height increases.
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consectetur porttitor neque at vestibulum. Nulla facilisi. Nullam tempus ligula sapien, dictum scelerisque libero tristique et. Ut sit amet magna eros. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae sodales nunc. Nunc eget condimentum urna. Nulla sit amet lectus ac nunc mattis porttitor eget quis purus. Ut rhoncus nulla eget velit tincidunt luctus. Donec in justo tempus, porttitor magna nec, semper eros. In bibendum magna eget lectus viverra ultricies. Integer pharetra augue lorem, eu tempus nulla volutpat dignissim.

    Morbi vulputate arcu sit amet lectus porttitor hendrerit. Donec id pharetra urna, sit amet tincidunt nulla. Nam semper felis vitae odio elementum posuere. Vivamus blandit accumsan sapien, vitae blandit est lacinia et. Nam sit amet diam massa. Quisque et erat et orci dignissim congue. Maecenas pellentesque pretium sodales. Donec pellentesque rhoncus tortor et hendrerit. Phasellus nec dictum mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce nec ligula mollis, iaculis est a, lobortis est. Phasellus faucibus varius arcu, eget volutpat quam venenatis vel. Sed felis nulla, pulvinar ut metus ac, luctus finibus tortor. Aliquam vulputate, nulla quis accumsan pretium, lacus elit sollicitudin ipsum, non faucibus erat mauris a felis.
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could do it with either margin-top or padding-top

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig padding-top, margin-top isn't the option here as the top div is of variable height, and i want the bottom div pushed as the height of fixed div changes in different pages which is not possible with fixed margins or padding

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, you need to set either padding-top or margin-top to your .bottom class :)

Comment: Check my answer now. This keeps the position fixed for top container and the below container will start with a padding of height of top container so it will not hide the below container behind top container

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig As I mentioned in my question "All I need is to push the bottom contents below the fixed div to re-position itself as the height of the fixed div changes in various pages." how do you suggest me to handle the fixed margin or padding added in bottom class if the height of the top fixed div is more than that in some page?

Comment: And unfortunately no one cares to explain what is the problem with my question or edit it, before or after down voting it. How do I know what needs to be improved here?

Comment: This is actually a decent question.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
.bottom {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1cm;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question "All I need is to push the bottom contents below the fixed div to re-position itself as the height of the fixed div changes in various pages." how do you suggest me to handle the fixed margin you added if the height of the top fixed div is more than 1cm in some page?

Comment: its for bottom div , what ever size you select for top div it will keep 1 cm margin from top div ... you tried it ? how you are getting div when size changes using this ?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if the height of the top div exceeds 1cm. And you can also try it by yourself by editing my code, you know. Just increase the contents of the top div so that its height exceeds 1cm and see what happens.

Answer (score -3):

I have **updated the fiddle** and its working:https://jsfiddle.net/m0615z32/1/

Below is a **pure javascript code that will work for you**. Please check
What i have done is set the **padding-top of below container to be equal to height of top container** without using jquery.

```
document.getElementById("bottom-div").style.paddingTop = document.getElementById("top-div").clientHeight+"px";
```

OR

**If You can change your top container to be relative than fixed, then also this works but is not keeping the div fixed on top**

```
.top {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
}
```

Now the top content will always be on top. It will adjust according to content and below container will start after top ends.

Comment: I hope this is what was required, even if not, then it should not have been down-voted. And i am sure what ii have answered suits the question and is the correct solution

Comment: I actually don't know who down voted it, but I can see why. My top div is a fixed content, which is supposed to stay so. But in your second solution you changed its position to relative. Secondly I was very clear about avoiding rendering issues caused by jquery, which has similar behavior for javascript too. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Shuvro: No rendering issue should happen if you use javascript code. Rest is on you to choose what you wanna do. Best of luck !!